# How to calculate time duration between two events in splunk which dont have common element

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-calculation

**First Event**

06:09:17:362 INFO com.x.y.ConnApp - Making a GET Request

**Second Event**

06:09:17:480 INFO com.a.b.Response - Output Status Code: 200

Now I want to calculate duration of these two events for every request. I went over the solutions on splunk and Stack Overflow, but still can't get the proper result.

Comment: What distinguishes the events for one request from those of other requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy answer is the `transaction` command, although it has a couple of drawbacks.  The first is the command can be a resource hog.  The other is can be "greedy" in that multiple requests might be taken to be a single transaction.  We'll take care of the second issue with the `maxevents` option.  There's not much we can do about the first except avoid using `transaction`.

```
index=foo ("Making a GET Request" OR "Output Status Code:")
| transaction maxevents=2 startswith="Making a GET Request" endswith="Output Status Code:"
| table duration
```

Another option uses the `streamstats` command to calculate the difference between adjacent events.  This should perform better than `transaction`.

````
index=foo ("Making a GET Request" OR "Output Status Code:")
| streamstats window=2 range(_time) as duration
``` Erase the duration field for start events. ```
| eval duration = if(searchmatch("Making a GET Request"),"", duration)
| table _raw duration
````

Both queries assume the start and end events for different requests are not intermingled.

Comment: if the events from different requests are intermingled, you can `sort` first - do this semifrequently

Answer (score 1):

With the current logging messages, it will be tricky to group logs who are linked by the same source (imagine multiple calls who generate successive *Making a GET* messages)

In this case, I suggest to spread a ‘*correlation Id*’ in the logging message

Then you can identify exactly the messages who are triggered by the same source

This involve a change of the app logging function (you can search the following libs: log4/mcd/sleuth)