# How to find time duration between two splunk events which has unique key

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-calculation

**First Event**

17:09:05:362 INFO com.a.b.App - Making a GET Request and req-id: [123456]

**Second Event**

17:09:06:480 INFO com.a.b.App - Output Status Code: 200 req-id:"123456"

I tried to use `index="xyz" container="service-name" | transaction "req-id" startswith="Making a GET Request" endswith="Output Status Code" | table duration` but it is also not working.

I want to calculate duration of above two events for every request. I went over some solutions in splunk and Stack Overflow, but still can't get the proper result.

Comment: are you `req_id` fields ever duplicated?

Comment: yes, in the middle one more log/event also has req-id

Comment: message-1: `com.a.d.controller : Request initiated x-req-id: [12345]`
message-2: `com.a.d.controller : header: x-req-id: 12345`
message-3: `com.a.d.service : Result of data: <200, x-req-id:"12345", .....`
I need to calculate time duration between message-1 and message-3

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it with `stats` instead:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp 
| rex field=_raw "req\-id\D+(?<req_id>\d+)"
| rex field=_raw "(?<sequence>Making a GET Request)"
| rex field=_raw "(?<sequence>Output Status Code)"
| eval sequence=sequence+";"+_time
| stats values(sequence) as sequence by req_id
| mvexpand sequence
| rex field=sequence "(?<sequence>[^;]+);(?<time>\d+)"
| eval time=strftime(time,"%c")
```

This will extract the "req-id" into a field named `req_id`, and the start and end of the sequence into a field named `sequence`

Presuming the sample data you shared is correct, when you `stats values(sequence) as sequence`, it will put the "Making..." entry first and the "Output..." entry second

Because `values()` will do this, when you `mvexpand` and then split the `values()`'d field part into `sequence` and `time`, they'll be in the proper order

If the sample data is incomplete, you may need to tweak the regexes for populating `sequence`

Comment: `sourcetype=xyz container_name="abc-mno"  
| rex field=_raw "x\-req\-id\S+(?<x_req_id>\d+)"  
| rex field=_raw "com.a.b.controller\- (?<sequence>Making a GET Request)" 
| rex field=_raw "com.a.b.Service\- (?<sequence>Output Status Code)"  
| eval sequence=sequence+";"+_time  
| stats values(sequence) as sequence by x_req_id  
| mvexpand sequence | rex field=sequence "(?<sequence>[^;]+);(?<time>\d+)" 
| eval time=strftime(time,"%c")`

 For above query, I am getting `Field 'sequence' does not exist in the data`

Comment: @Sat - it sounds like you've got a formatting issue in the regex. What does your sample data *actually* look like?

Comment: I have provided my sample data only in the above query.. only different is with sourceType, container-name, package, class-names and text messages. 

message-1: `com.a.d.controller : Request initiated x-req-id: [12345]`
message-2: `com.a.d.service : Result of data: <200, x-req-id:"12345", .....`

Comment: @Sat - see my update: try changing "`\S+`" to "`\D+`" in the `req_id` extraction

Comment: I tried by changing `\S+` with `\D+` but still same issue

Comment: @Sat - I shortened the `rex` line

Answer (score 0):

It’s seem you’re going [with my previously suggested approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75204313/6215824)

Now you have 2 possibilities

**1. SPL**

Below the simplest query, only invoking 1 rex and assuming _time field correctly filled

```
index=<your_index> source=<your_source>
("*Making a GET Request*" OR "*Output Status Code*")
| rex field=_raw "req\-id\D+(?<req_id>\d+)"
| stats max(_time) as end, min(_time) as start by id
| eval duration = end - start
| table id duration
```

Note that depending the amount of data to scan, this one can be ressources consuming for your Splunk cluster

**2. Log the response time directly in API (more efficient)**

It seem you are working on an API. You must have capabilities to get the response time of each call and directly trace it in your log

Then you can exploit it easily in SPL without calculation

It always preferable to persist data at index time vs. operate systematic calculation at search time